# How to replace Facebook parse API to a custom domain server

Tags: api, parse-platform

Parse is awesome. But I want to handle all request from my own server. Since parse has been open sourced. I'd like to know if it is possible to replace the default server api.parse.com to api.mydomain.com.

Sorry no code. I just need a way to implement such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Nope, doesn't work that way.

### Long Answer

There's a ***massive*** difference between Parse open-sourcing their SDKs compared to revealing their entire backend architecture and its configuration.

The open-sourced SDKs are essentially wrappers for Parse's REST API along with some convenience functions and logic for natively interpreting the JSON data Parse is transmitting.

At a high level, Parse uses MongoDB for its core database and is entirely hosted using AWS (Amazon Web Services). The entire architecture is highly complex and is not something you could just drag and drop onto your own software stack or hardware backend.

It would be easier to build out all of your own backend services on AWS than it would be to try to clone Parse but for only one app. For example you could use AWS S3 for storage needs and then access those resources using AWS API Gateway which will automatically create mobile platform SDKs for you.

To help give you a better idea of how Parse achieves all of their services, [here's an interesting presentation their Dev Ops team gave at an AWS convention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTjmG3b22I). Suffice it to say, hosting the backend services for over 180,000 apps requires a complex infrastructure and that's the "secret sauce" for Parse, and is also why Facebook purchased them for over $85 million two years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. :D

Comment: Sure thing! Go ahead and mark as answer to close this out unless you have anymore questions :)

Comment: Oh sorry bout that. I thought up-voting makes it as answered. Thanks again.